# Searching for files in directory by DATE using cmd

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I want to create a bat file that copies all jpeg image files created on a specific date - eg 2013/05/05.

It will go something like this:

```
xcopy g:\DCIM\images\'command for date'*.jpg c:\users\david\images\newImages
```

How do I accomplish that?

I tried the following but it copied all the images in the folder and ignore the date param:

```
xcopy /l /s /d:05-05-2013 g:\DCIM\images\*.jpg c:\users\david\images\newImages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=1,5 delims= " %%a in ('dir /a-d /tc G:\DCIM\images\*.jpg') do (
   if %%a equ 2013/05/05 copy "g:\DCIM\images\%%b" "c:\users\david\images\newImages"
)
```

Comment: thanks, but does not seem to work

Comment: could you perhaps test the code?

Comment: Is your date format yyyy/dd/mm the way you posted it? type `DIR` at a `CMD` prompt and see what the date format is. Change the date to whatever format it's in. I don't post code unless I've tested it. It works fine on my system. I've refined it a little in case you didn't run the batch file from the G:\dcim\images directory.

Comment: There's also the issue with 24 hour time and 12 hour time and the AM/PM line which throws off the calculation.

Comment: quite apart from `spaces` in file names and `directories`.

Comment: @foxidrive - I've never used 24 hour time, so I didn't account for it like I should have. Luckily, the op apparently uses 12 hour time.

Comment: @Endoro - both valid points. I've quoted the filenames and removed searching directories.

Comment: One question though - What language is this? Why do you use the code you have and not something more simple like the code I have used?

Comment: Language? Like English or the programming lang? When you use the /d parameter of xcopy, it copies files changed on or after the specified date. That means it uses the last modified date and not the creation date that you specified and you'd get all files from your date until now. To get the creation date, you have to do `DIR` and use the /tc switch and copy the files based on a specified date that is the first field of the `DIR` command.

Comment: ok I see. thanks. Yes, the "@echo off
setlocal for..."...Is that c++ or just normal command line code? How do you know this? Do you know a programming language do be able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@echo off&setlocal
cd /d "g:\DCIM\images"
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('dir ^|findstr "^[0-9]"') do set "AMPM=%%i"
if "%AMPM:M=%"=="%AMPM%" (set "AMPM=3") else set "AMPM=4"
for /f "tokens=1,%AMPM%*" %%i in ('dir /a-d /tc *.jpg') do if "05-05-2013"=="%%i" echo copy "%%k" "c:\users\david\images\newImages"
```

Comment: thank you...but does not work...Isn't there an easier way to do this - see my updated answer

Comment: Imo you gave a wrong date format. You should provide first a sample output from your "dir" command.

Comment: not sure what the format should be then...since I used the specified xcopy format...which is /D:m-d-y

Comment: @DextrousDave - I made my **last** edit, changed the compare date. For any more help you **must** provide your date format from the "dir" command. Type "dir" on the command line, copy the output and paste it here. Xcopy is not useful here.

Comment: copied dir...see update

Comment: Tried your code again, with the date format changed to: 2013/05/05 - As it is listed in DIR command.However, Matt's answer below works for the 2013/05/05 date format